# Batch Consumer with a given period doesn't work with multiple partition in Spring Cloud Stream(StreamListener)?

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing, spring-cloud-stream

```
    @StreamListener(value = PersonStream.INPUT)
    private void personBulkReceiver(List<Person> person) {
    //....
    }

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      binders:
        bulkKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.records: 1500
                        fetch.min.bytes: 10000000
                        fetch.max.wait.ms: 10000
                        value.deserializer: tr.cloud.stream.examples.PersonDeserializer
      bindings:
        person-topic-in:
          binder: bulkKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/person
          group : person-group
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
```

I'am using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka. In a StreamListener when partition count is 1 I can consume records in batch mode in every 5000 ms.

My .yml configuration is **fetch.min.bytes = 10000000 && fetch.max.wait.ms = 50000 && max.poll.records = 1500** as stated above.

I can receive batch records in every 5000 ms. since batch record size doesn't exceed 10000000 bytes.

But when partition count is more than 1 StreamListener consumes records earlier than 5000 ms.

Is there any configuration for this case?

Or is this case is the natural result of independent threads working for each partition?

When partition count is more than 1 what is the difference in working logic ?

Comment: You can set the `concurrency` to equal the number of partitions; you'll then get one consumer thread per partition.

Comment: Can you explain the working logic a little bit more? If I don't make any additional configuration(in default mode) what is the relationship between consumer thread and partition count? And what is the logic behind concurrency configuration?
@GaryRussell

Comment: By default, all the partitions will be assigned to a single thread; so your fetch properties apply across all partitions, which means they will be satisfied earlier (assuming there are enough records). By increasing the concurrency to match the partition count, the properties will only be applied to one partition for each thread.

Comment: In my application I have one topic with 3 partitions. StreamListener is triggered three times in 5000 ms. when partition count is 3. When I set partition count to 1, the StreamListener is triggered once in 5000 ms. which is what I want to do. With 3 partitions, I have set concurrency attribute to 3, but StreamListener is still being triggered 3 times in 5000 ms. I could not achieve StreamListener to be triggered once in 5000 ms. when partion count is more than one.

Comment: With concurrency = 3 each consumer is independent so, yes, you will get multiple calls per 5 seconds. With concurrency set to 1, there will be one consumer for all 3 partitions. If the partitions are on different brokers, a separate fetch request is sent to each broker, so that might be why you are seeing that behavior (but that's a guess). But I haven't been able to reproduce it, even with 3 brokers.

Comment: I have one broker, and only one application is running with a StreamListener. When the partition count is more than one, StreamListener is triggered multiple time in 5000 ms. regardless of the concurrency parameter. When the partition count is one, StreamListener is triggered once in 5000ms. which is my intention.

Comment: It doesn't make sense if the aggregate records across the partitions don't meet your configured limits; and, as I said, I can't reproduce it; post a small, complete, stripped down example that exhibits this behavior and perhaps someone can figure out what's wrong. Clearly, your verbal description is not enough since I have an app with 3 partitions and it only gets called once per 5 seconds.

Comment: @Gary, I want to understand the behavior you expect. 1 or 2 ?

1. Situation :  It comes to streamlistener once for each partition within 5 seconds. In other words, if there are 10 partitions, it comes to streamlistener 10 times in 5 seconds.

2. Situation : Within 5 seconds, regardless of the number of partitions, it come once.

Comment: @Gary. 2 years have passed, but I still could not get past this problem. I would be very happy if you could help me understand.

Comment: As I said back then `>It doesn't make sense if the aggregate records across the partitions don't meet your configured limits; and, as I said, I can't reproduce it; post a small, complete, stripped down example that exhibits this behavior and perhaps someone can figure out what's wrong. Clearly, your verbal description is not enough since I have an app with 3 partitions and it only gets called once per 5 seconds.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok gary. I made a sample project. Please read the readme file. Thank you again.
https://gitlab.com/omercelikcengg/spring-cloud-stream-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your readme...

> And there is always a lot of data on the topic.

So that doesn't match your question where you said...

> I can receive batch records in every 5000 ms. since batch record size doesn't exceed 10000000 bytes.

When there is more data than that, it will always be pushed to the client.

Consider using a [Polled Consumer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers) instead, to receive data at your desired rate.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary. I have kept you very busy. Actually, the fact that these configurations work on a section basis confuses me. I thought it worked like this: The data is polled according to the specified configuration, then waited for 5 seconds and the data is polled again according to the specified configuration. However, the fact that there are partition-specific settings confuses me. That's why I kept you so busy. Thanks again.

Comment: You can use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` to set the container property `idleBetweenPolls` - this will sleep for that time before polling again. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/9f48d0075836d4ecac931a4649e2d3e73e558121/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.java#L617-L626 But with concurrency, you'll get records on each thread, according to the settings.